# symfony 1.4, $this->save() and mysql insert triggers

Tags: mysql, triggers, symfony-1.4, propel

I have an on-insert trigger that updates a product code in a table, based on a customer's most recent code, stored in another table.

With symfony and Propel, I am doing the following (truncated unnecessary fields)

```
// actions.class.php
$lineitem = new LineItem();
$lineitem->setCustomerId( $customerId );

$thisProduct = ProductPeer::cacheProduct($orderDetails);
$lineitem->setCode($thisProduct->getCode()); // this should be fetching and setting the auto_code, inserted from the trigger.
$lineitem->save();
```

The cacheProduct function (part of ProductPeer) below

```
// ProductPeer.php
// auto_code field in DB left blank, ready to be written to by the trigger
// cacheProduct function
public static function cacheProduct($orderDetails)
{
    $product = new Product();
    $product->setName( $orderDetails->getName() ); 
    $product->setCustomerCode( $orderDetails->getCustomerCode() );
    //$product->setCode(); // this will be set by the TRIGGER on insert.
    $product->save();

    return $product->getId();
}
```

So the problem is that the product is being inserted, and the trigger is being run successfully, but Symfony is never aware of the newly inserted 'code' value. Running a fresh **ProductPeer::retrieveByPK()** still shows an empty 'code' field.

So in essence, at all points, **$lineitem->getCode()** returns null.

I've tried wrapping this in transactions, but it shouldn't be necessary ... and also there is potential for this to be in a loop and I don't want to open and close transactions repeatedly unless absolutely necessary.

1) When does a MYSQL trigger actually run ... on **$xxx->save()**? At the end of the script?
2) How can I access this value post-trigger, while still in the same script?

Solution found, thank you :)
Working with Propel version 1.4.8 or greater

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set

```
reloadOnInsert="true"
```

on your table schema, and rebuild your model: [Example](http://www.propelorm.org/reference/schema.html#table_attributes)

(Be aware that this may have been introduced in a more recent version of Propel - check the version of your Propel plugin.)

Comment: Fantastic, that does solve the problem! :) Is there any way that I can flag the table to do that on a DB level, so that when using propel:build-schema, reloadOnInsert: true gets added to schema.yml automatically?

Comment: Great - would you tick my answer? (it's how we mark a correct answer on S/O). I don't think there is any way to get that attribute into the schema automatically, but once you have set that up, you shouldn't need (imo) to regenerate the schema anyway. Your schema should be your definitive database definition, and you should rebuild your database instead whenever the model changes. Use fixtures to reset the database to a known state, and optionally use migrations (though I've never needed that).

Comment: already ticked, you were so quick with your answer that I had to wait to accept it! :)

Comment: Thanks - the benefit of answering questions at the top of the S/O homepage ;-)